# Compression using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, compression

I am using compression library in nodejs,
I understand it can be used to compress API responses it make them lighter, especially if the API consumers are mobile applications.
Found a simple example online but, it's giving me an error when I run the code.

**Referring the following site -**
https://codeforgeek.com/2017/05/lossless-compression-http-request-response-nodejs-server-4013/

**The code provided is as follows -**

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// compress all requests 
app.use(compression())

// add all routes 
app.get('/compressed',function (req,res){
    res.write('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

**When I try to run the code I get the following error -**

```
/home/user/office/node-crud-app/Node-Tutorials/Apps/compression.js:10
router.get('*',(req,res) => {
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/Node-Tutorials/Apps/compression.js:10:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:990:3
```

**How can I resolve it?**

Comment: did you create a nodejs/npm project?

Comment: yes project name is "node-crud-app", also installed compression using the command "npm install compression", then created a js files called "compression.js".

Comment: tried àpp.get('/'), same error.

Comment: works on my machine ;-) npm install express, npm install compression, start with node compression.js

Comment: Exact same code? Can you post your running code?

Comment: copy&paste, just replaced `res.write(...)` with `res.send(...)` to close the connection. How do you run it?

Comment: resolved, thanks :)